# Referencing an Objects data into another object -> object.property.OTHEROBJECT.PROPERTY.length

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects, `player` and `rooms`

I have a `ul` tag of which i would like to populate the `li` depending on how many options there are and depending on where the player is.

I have the following

```
let player = {
  name: "",
  location: "start"
}

let rooms = {
  start: {
       name: "outside",
       test: "testing",
       options:{
            option1: "Option 1",
            option2: "OPtion 2"
       }
      },
    end:{
      name: "outside",
       test: "testing",
       options:{
            option1: "start",
            option2: "end"

        }
    }
}


for (let key in rooms.start.options){
  let option = document.createElement("li");                 
option.innerHTML = (rooms.(player.location).options[key]);
optionsList.appendChild(option)
  console.log();
}
```

I am unsure how to reference the player location in the last few lines that so I can have either:

`option.innerHTML = (rooms.start.options[key]);` or

`option.innerHTML = (rooms.end.options[key]);`

some people are advising to use arrays but I like to reference such as `player.name`, `player.location`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

using `Bracket notation`

```
for (let key in rooms.start.options){
   console.log(rooms[player.location].options[key]); 
}
```

Hope it helps